# Web Socket is not working for actual device after upgrading server from 2012 to 2019

Tags: .net, ssl, websocket, iot, tls1.2

We have a backend application that can connect from mobile and an actual IOT based Device. We used Web Socket with WCF as a structure. As before somedays, Azure stops to support TLS10, we need to upgrade the Notification library forcefully. For that we upgraded to .NET framework 4.8 and all libraries upgraded.

Currently, we have a dev environment without an SSL certificate, and a staging environment with SSL enabled.
We deploy code in both servers, but in the Dev server, it's working fine,

In the staging server, Hard devices (not mobile) are not connecting via Web Socket.
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to look at is the SSL/TLS version supported. newer version of operating systems do restrict and turn of the more unsecure versions of TLS/SSL, so that can be a a source for your problems.

Comment: Do you mean windows server 2019 restricted? We can't change any code on the device side. That's why I am asking further.

Comment: i mean newer versions might "turn off" insecure protocols by default, to make them more secure.. so it could be one reason....

Comment: Understood! We need to enable SSLv3.0 in server 2019. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, if your client requires that, but at the same time its important to beware that SSL is no longer "secure"

Comment: TLS is the replacement for SSL. So make sure you check what versions your client support TLS/SSL...

Comment: does that make my answer an acceptable answer?

Comment: Actually, We can not change device code. And we enabled all TLS1.0, TLS12, SSL2.0, SSL3.0. but not success yet.

Comment: If you have SSL trouble, it can also be the ciphers supported. Besides the protocol (SSL/TLS) you also exchange the ciphers. But to better figure out , I would try to look at the logs (perhaps increase the log level to debug or trace), to see why the client can't connect9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229133/discussion-between-darshit-gandhi-and-tore-nestenius).